# Tableau public refuses to start even after turning UAC off

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to install tableau public. After installation, when i try to run it, it says its failing to start because of product binaries. The support says that I must turn off User Access control to fix the problem. I switched off the UAC using both the control panel and registry but when trying to start tableau public it still says product binaries

I'm using the tableau public version 2020.2.2 and windows 8

Comment: I get the same error trying to open Tableau Public. So it may not be an installation issue. Suprisingly nothing yet on Twitter about this. Sure it can't only be you and I with a problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Tableau Public issue was solved by uninstalling and reinstalling